# Rank columns and put the column with the highest score as first and so on

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say i have a very large data.frame containing scores per column.

for example:

```
MA0001.1 AGL3 MA0003.1 TFAP2A MA0004.1 Arnt  MA0005.1 AG   MA0006.1 Arnt::Ahr
7.789524e-09  0.4012127249    3.771518e-03   1.892011e-06  0.002733200
5.032498e-07  0.0001873801    9.947449e-05   3.284222e-05  0.001367041
1.194487e-06  0.0009357406    6.943634e-05   1.589373e-05  0.002551519
4.833494e-06  0.0150703600    1.003488e-04   1.197928e-03  0.001431416
6.865040e-05  0.0000732607    3.857193e-04   5.388744e-03  0.001363706
```

R data.frame:

```
testfr<-structure(list(`MA0001.1 AGL3` = c(7.78952366977488e-09, 5.03249791215203e-07, 
1.19448739380034e-06, 4.83349413748598e-06, 6.86504034402563e-05
), `MA0003.1 TFAP2A` = c(0.401212724871542, 0.000187380067026448, 
0.000935740631438077, 0.0150703600158589, 7.32607018758816e-05
), `MA0004.1 Arnt` = c(0.00377151826447817, 9.94744903768433e-05, 
6.94363387424972e-05, 0.000100348764966112, 0.00038571926458373
), `MA0005.1 AG` = c(1.89201084302835e-06, 3.2842217133538e-05, 
1.58937284554136e-05, 0.00119792816070882, 0.00538874414923338
), `MA0006.1 Arnt::Ahr` = c(0.00273319966783363, 0.00136704060025893, 
0.00255151921946167, 0.00143141576426544, 0.00136370552325235
)), .Names = c("MA0001.1 AGL3", "MA0003.1 TFAP2A", "MA0004.1 Arnt", 
"MA0005.1 AG", "MA0006.1 Arnt::Ahr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(4L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 3L))
```

Now i want to select the column with the highest values in it and place that column first.
So the values of 1 column should stay below the same column name and the entire column should move by rank.

I tried the following:

```
ranked<-unlist(lapply(testfr,rank))
testranked<-testfr[ranked, ]
```

this produces a data frame with 2259obs*459vars while the original was 5*459.

Note that, testfr is a data.frame derived from a function which scores sequences on to a list of matrices! And gives that score back into a data.frame where the rows are the sequences and the columns are the matrices.

I know i do something wrong with the indexing or unlisting but i dont have any clue how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
> testfr[rev(order(sapply(testfr, max, na.rm = TRUE)))]
```

Break down:

```
sapply(test.fr, max, na.rm = TRUE) # get max of each column (after removing NA)
order(.) # get the order of these values in increasing order
rev(.)   # get the reverse order so that highest value index stays first
testfr[.] # get the columns in this order back
```

Comment: nice chaining of functions :)

Comment: @Arun indeed nice chaining of functions. But when applying it to the test data set i still believe that the output is not correct yet. Because the columns won't change by maximum. and the order of the old frame column.names is the same as the new frame, only the values are ordered but not the columns

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, Do you have `NA` values in your data.frame?

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, try it now. there was a `,` before `]`, that was the problem. I've also made sure to account for `NA` values.

Comment: @Arun NO i dont, but i solved the problem, maybe not in the most beautiful way but it works. when deleting rev from the chain of functions and do rev afterwards. So `x<-testfr[order(sapply(testfr, max)), ]` and than `y<-rev(x)`

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, try the edited solution. It'll work. As I said, there was a `,` before the last `]` which was the problem. What you're doing will sort the values within column as well. It is wrong.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the fix and good explanation i marked youre answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `apply` for readability,

```
testfr[order(apply(testfr, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE),decreasing=T)]
```

I apply max for each margin , column here, Then I sort column in decreasing order.

Comment: But it would internally convert to a `matrix` before "apply"ing. I don't see why one would want to use `apply`... thanks for the option of `decreasing = TRUE` in order though.

Comment: @agstudy Thanks for the other option! i will have a look at it. But Arun was first so i will accept his answer as the correct 1. Also could you give me an explanation why you choose decreasing? because i want to select on the highest scores

Comment: @Arun I think here it has a data.frame not a list, so using `apply` is natural for me.

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw `decreasing = TRUE` means form the high to the low value. Since you want the Highest score.

Comment: @agstudy do this:`df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol=1e3))` `system.time(t1 <- sapply(df, mean))` `system.time(t2 <- apply(df, 2, mean))`

Comment: @Arun i get your point. but I am not fun of `sapply`. I use `apply` or `lapply`:  `apply` for a matrix or data.frame , `lapply` for a list.  The performance problem doesn't matter for me at least at this point of the OP question. The code looks more readable for me.

Comment: Even then, a `data.frame` is internally a `list`. So, I don't see why you choose not to use `lapply` on a `data.frame` (as `apply` calls `as.matrix(.)` within). Anyway, I seem to have gotten my point thro'. All is well.